# PHP MyAdmin:Table relation view is not working

Tags: php, mysql

My table engine is `InnoDB`.A month ago, I was able to see and create table relations, but now, when I press `Relation view` in `Structure` tab, I see only `Foreign key constraints` table.However I need to see relation or design view, to be able to create relations between tables.

Here is the screen:

[image]